# Expression Blend integration with source control?

Tags: wpf, version-control, expression-blend

I have a WPF project in Visual Studio 2012. It have it all set up with source control, so that if I try to edit a file that I don't have checked, it will automatically try to check it out, and then allow me to edit it.

Is this supposed to work in Expression Blend 2012 as well?

If I open the same project in Expression Blend, it lets me edit a non-checked-out file, and I may not even realize that I don't have the file checked out until I try and save it, and it tells me that the file is read-only.

Is there something that I have to do to enable source control in Blend?  Or, does Blend not even support source control integration?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds more like a setting issue. In Visual Studio, there is an 'Allow checked-in item to be edited' option at Tools->Options->Source Control->Environment. Please make sure you uncheck it.

Blend supports source control integration. [This blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudiouk/archive/2012/09/15/enabling-tfs-source-control-with-expression-blend-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx) might help.

Comment: Yes, that is already unchecked in Visual Studio, but Blend doesn't have that menu.

Comment: I looked at that blog article, but I'm not using Team Foundation.  I'm using a 3rd party source control solution (SourceAnywhere), so I don't think it applies.

Comment: Glad to hear that you are using SourceAnywhere for source control. I work for the company. :) It seems Expression Blend only supports TFS currently.